# Histogram and Around

Tags: plotting, histograms

If I have histogram as

```
Labeled[Histogram[{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,
                   1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2}, 
   ChartStyle -> Red, LabelStyle -> {18, GrayLevel[0]}],
   {Rotate[Style["Number of cities", FontFamily -> "Times"], 90 Degree],
   Style["Number of crimes", FontFamily -> "Times"]}, {Left, Bottom},
   LabelStyle -> {18, GrayLevel[0]}]
```

which looks like:
[image]

How can I add error bars, let's say: $0.5$, $0.4$, and $0.3$, using Around command?

Comment: I don't think you can do that directly using `Histogram`. You can probably build your own histogram using `BarChart` and `BinCounts`, where you can use `Around` to specify error bars. Alternatively, you can keep the histogram and use `ListPlot` and `BinCounts` to genereate the error bars, which you could the combine with the histogram using `Show`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `HistogramList` and count between say 0 to 3 with stepsize 1.

```
h = HistogramList[{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
                   1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2}, {0, 3, 1}];
nh = Length[h[[2]]]
err = {0.5, 0.4, 0.3}; (*set by hand*)
ListPlot[Table[{h[[1, i]], Around[h[[2, i]], err[[i]]]}, {i, nh}]]
```